# Angular - How to return subscribe data

Tags: angular, firebase

I'm trying to return the data I get from a query with firease using Ionic and Angular, but the array returns 'undefined'

```
  QueryList (id: string ) {    

    this.db.collection('/list', ref => ref.where('id', '==', id)).valueChanges().subscribe(ref => {return ref});

  }
```

What would be the correct syntax to return the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return the observable and subscribe where the data is needed

```js
QueryList (id: string ): Observable<any> {    
  return this.db.collection('/list', ref => ref.where('id', '==', id)).valueChanges();
}
```

Component

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.someService.QueryList(id).subscribe(ref => {this.ref = ref});
}
```

The data is asynchronous and it isn't possible to return the value synchronously.

More details on how to access asynchronous data [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/6513921).

Comment: Thanks, that way the data returns correctly and thanks for the info :)